# JSGrid not showing filter input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsgrid

I want the input filter fields to get created and shown under the header row cells as expected.

In my MVC solution i have my JSGrid populating via AJAX/JSON/GET. I'm able to sort and step into the loadData javascript etc. When I add "filtering:true" a row with cells are generated between the header row and table body rows but the the input fields are not there. I've tried including different CSS, JQuery and JS libraries and tried to mimic many demo's and samples..

```
function RenderImportHistory() {
    $("#jsGrid_ImportHistory").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "572px",
        pageSize: 10,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        filtering: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,

        loadIndication: true,
        loadIndicationDelay: 500,
        loadMessage: "Getting Import History ...",

        controller: {
            loadData: function (filter) {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetImportHistory", "SCAL", new { Area = "Admin" })",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                }).done(function(result) {
                    /*result = $.grep(result, function(item) {
                        return item.patientId === filter.patientId
                           && item.patientName === filter.patientName
                           && item.genderId === filter.genderId
                           && item.mobile === filter.mobile;

                    }); */
                    d.resolve(result);
                });
                return d.promise();
            }
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "ID", type: "Number", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 11, sorter:"number" },
            { name: "ImportSched_ID", type: "Number", title: "Schedule", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 27, sorter:"number" },
            { name: "Created", type: "Text", title: "Started", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatDateTime(value); } },
            { name: "Completed", type: "Text", title: "Ended", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatDateTime(value); } },
            { name: "NumOfClaims", type: "Number", title: "Claims", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 21, sorter: "number", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatCounts(value); } },
            { name: "NumOfRecords", type: "Number", title: "Rows", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 21, sorter: "number", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatCounts(value); } },
            { name: "TimeToRead_Seconds", type: "Number", title: "Read", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 21, sorter: "number", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatDuration(value); } },
            { name: "TimeToWrite_Seconds", type: "Number", title: "Wrote", css: "jsGrid_Body", headercss: "jsGrid_Head", width: 21, sorter: "number", itemTemplate: function (value) { return FormatDuration(value); } }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have something in your jsGrid_Head css that's hiding text fields, maybe? Side note, you can just return the $.ajax instead of the $.Deferred extra step, as long as you also remove the .done.

Comment: Looking at the generated HTML/CSS the TRs & TDs are there for the filter row/cells but nothing is within the TDs.. I took out all my custom CSS related to the JS Grid just to be sure but still nada. Here's what it does generate:  
<tr class="jsgrid-filter-row"><td class="jsgrid-cell jsGrid_Body"></td>..

i was messing with the clientside filtering trying different examples, at this point i'm just going to manually define some fields to filter above the grid. I'm thinking it has to be something with the included libs versions etc. their demo is simple but they use many small local includes

Comment: i should probably try doing exactly what the demo does and use all their exact included JS & CSS libs, opposed to 1 CDN hosted lib.. next i'm going to go for JqGrid.. I was really liking this JsGrid until this. Ultimately I need my new employer to buy Kendo UI :-)

Comment: I've tried your code in my page that does this, and even stripping your grid essentially bare, it still doesn't show the filtering, so I'm stumped so far.

Comment: yea this is pretty strange, seems like it should be real simple, but yet, no dice. thanks for your help and trying to run it, helps to prove out the includes theory to..  thnx again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it's actually pretty simple, and pretty silly, too. It's so silly and simple that it's too easy to miss. Change your type declarations in your fields to all lowercase.

type: "Number" >> type: "number"

and

type: "Text" >> type: "text"

The developers should have this case insensitive, but lazy devs....

Comment: ehhy, my man!! <high-five!> .. ugh, i'm pretty sure i started with a copy/paste and that's how it got it :-)    thanks so much ! . id up vote but it looks like i'm way Noob yet on here. ;- |

Comment: Well, maybe you'll get a few more up votes and can be able to up vote then. You might also be able to get the ability to Accept this answer, too, is you get enough votes.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to raise this as a bug on the JSGrid GitHub page. It's not exactly a bug, but it's pretty silly to have unexpected results when a text attribute isn't lowercase. I know it's a requirement in HTML attributes, but it's still silly, IMO.

Comment: yea, it'd probably be considered an enhancement.. JavaScript is a case sensitive language yano but like you said it's an attribute and the values are 'types' defined in the JsGrid Libs opposed to language types or anything..  what's "FWIW" and "IMO" stand for?

Comment: FWIW: for what it's worth. IMO: in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this topic has been open for a long time. But I had the same problem and using the **heading: true** property works for me